# cascading delete in MySQL console

Tags: mysql, sql

In order to maintain referential integrity I have foreign key constraints set on several tables, *without* `ON CASCADE DELETE`.

However at times I'd like to relax that a bit, the prime example being when in a development environment I'd like to create a trimmed/sanitized copy of a production dataset. So I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
DELETE FROM x WHERE foo = 'bar'
```

and have rows in another table `y` that reference the deleted rows in `x` also be deleted. Currently with my constraints in place this fails with:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Is there some way to do this in MySQL without altering the table? I vaguely remember something like `DELETE CASCADE FROM x WHERE foo = 'bar'` from Oracle or perhaps Postgres, but I'm unsure how to do this in MySQL.

I'm aware of `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0`, but that will simply leave the dangling references in `y`; I want them to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DELETE x, y
FROM  x 
      INNER JOIN y ON x.foo = y.foo
WHERE x.foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: That's fine in simple cases, but sometimes there are multiple levels (x -> y -> z, etc). Ideally I'd like to cascade the deletes automatically without specifying the joins manually.